# Angular ng-repeat with Json and $http ajax displays an empty list

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to display a list of elements by **name** and **id** with `ng-repeat` from a json with a super simple ajax request.

```
    var form = $("#loadAllServiceEngineForm");
    var url = form.attr("action");

    var App = angular.module('AdamApp', []);

    App.controller('locContol', function($scope, $http) {
        // Simple GET request
        $http.get(url).
          success(function(data) {
              $scope.locations = angular.fromJson(data);
              console.log(data);
          }).
          error(function(data) {
              console.error("NON CARICA I DATI");
        });
     });
```

In this list

```
    <body ng-app="AdamApp">
     <div ng-controller="locContol">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="location in locations |  orderBy: 'id'">
                <div>{{location.name}}-{{location.id}}</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </body>
```

The strange thing is which it return a list of empty `<li>`, and in console i see the strange Array attached.

[image: console log angular]

And this is the full json in console.log.

[image: full json]

I don't know angular, i'm just trying for the first time... but i see the difference between `jQuery` ie. when i call the same `json` with `$.ajax` and then  parse with `JSON.parse(data[i]);` it display in console an ordinate list of objects instead this strange array of objects.

[image: console log jquery]

How i can get a same result in angular?

Comment: When going from jquery to angular, do not think like jquery! I too made this same mistake, it has a totally different take on things. Use the `.then` method while will give you the response data available and you wont need to do any json parsing.

Comment: try replacing angular.json from JSON.parse ..

Comment: don't write `$scope.locations = angular.fromJson(data);`. then check your console

Comment: i've added an other image with the full `json` in `console`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.then` instead of `.success` to handle the callback. Also use `response.data` to get the parsed JSON response

```
$http.get(url)
     .then(function(response) {
          $scope.locations = response.data;
          console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function(data) {
          console.error("NON CARICA I DATI");
      });
```

For handling the error you can either pass the error callback as second parameter to `.then` or as part of `.catch` parameter. The preferred way is to use `.catch` as it handles errors, if any, from the success callback as well.

**UPDATED HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="location in locations track by $index |  orderBy: 'id'">
  <div>{{location.name}}-{{location.id}}</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The error i get is: `ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Comment: ofcourse `data` is not defined. One cannot simply write `response.data` unless we know there is a key `data` in the `response` object

Comment: I've try to make `console.log(response)` to see the full json. I've added an other image. I see the `data` as an `Array` with other two array inside... i'm wrong?

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo from copy paste. It should be `response.data` instead of `data`. Now the code should log and work fine

Comment: Yes, with `response.data` it get the `Array` i've posted in the first image and the ui is an empty list of `<li>` with nothing inside

Comment: The error is you have duplicates in your code, as shown in error. I have updated the html code to fix that issue.

Comment: @Avantikasaini: When you use `$http`, all responses are wrapped so that actual response will be an object containing `data`, `config`, `status`, `headers`, and `statusText` . Refer this link for details: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: the only way i can get some results is 
                                   `$scope.locations = [
                    angular.fromJson(response.data[0]),
                    angular.fromJson(response.data[1])
                ];
               alert($scope.locations[0].id);`